# python : NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined running kivy app

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, restructuredtext, docutils

I have created an app in android using kivy and buildozer. Without rst module the app runs ok, but when I use rst in the app I got the following error:

```
01-30 13:42:04.676  5746  5823 I python  :    File 
".../files/app/crystax_python/site-packages/docutils/__init__.py", 
line 112, in <module>
01-30 13:42:04.677  5746  5823 I python  :      class 
ApplicationError(StandardError):
01-30 13:42:04.677  5746  5823 I python  :  NameError: name 
'StandardError' is not defined
01-30 13:42:04.917  5746  5823 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

It seems the error happens because the docutils used by crystax is using python2 and standardError belongs to python2, even I'm building the app with python3.

By the way, in laptop the app runs ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your assessment looks reasonable, but I don't know why docutils wouldn't work, it should have been installed in a normal way using pip. Did you include it by just putting `docutils` in your requirements?

Comment: to @inclement : yes, I have installed docutils, but the package I'm importing is rst which import docutils. I wonder why in laptop works but in android gets  the error mentioned.